# Error in enum C# when placing arithmetic sign

Tags: c#, asp.net, enumeration

I am filling a combobox through one in ASP.NET MVC using C#, in that combo are filled as options of the arithmetic operators combo, but I only require the symbol (+, -, *, /), when I place only the sign it generates an error

[image]

I have already placed double and single quotation marks but it still marks me that an identifier was expected, there is also another way placing the tag [Description (...)] but I have not been able to bind this tag, the way the combo bin is:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DDLOperadores", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(EnumOperadores.MuestraOperadores)), "Selecciona el Tipo", new { @class = "form-control col-md-12" })
```

Comment: You cannot start an identifier off with anything other than a character, furthermore you cannot use symbols in identifiers.  So just name your enum `Plus` and `Minus`, `Positive` and `Negative`, `Add` and `Subtract`, etc, etc

Comment: enums don't allow operators like + and -

Comment: @TMcKeown its not specific to enum, you cannot name a variable/property/field anything except an apha-numeric character (as long as it starts with an alpha)

Answer (score 10):

You can't have symbols or only numbers in your identifiers.

I believe what you're wanting is this:

```
public enum MuestraOperadores
{
    [Description("+")]
    Plus = 1,

    [Description("-")]
    Minus = 2
}
```

Then on your ComboBox you can use the Description attribute as what will display to the user.

Comment: Its a little more complicated to get the Description attribute, you might want to include how to retrieve that (especially considering the way the OP is passing these enum values)

Comment: how can I retrieve the descriptions in my html tag? @Html.DropDownList("DDLOperadores", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(EnumOperadores.MuestraOperadores)), "Selecciona el Tipo", new { @class = "form-control col-md-12" })